# Grease Pencil Wont Convert into Bezier curves in Blender V2.80 beta

Tags: grease-pencil, bezier-curves

I'm following Jama Jurabaev's Blender tutorials from the Gumroad where he takes lines made with grease pencil and converts them into Bezier curves.

For some reason Blender 2.8B wont let me follow the same steps. I have my grease pencil model drawn up and all my control points selected while in edit mode, however when I click on the "strokes" button there is no option under the strokes drop down tab to  convert to Bezier.

The Convert to bezier option only appears in object mode, but nothing shows up when I convert to Bezier from object mode.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would really appreciate the help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with that tutorial but this is how I do it in Blender V2.80 beta, a bit different to V2.79b. 
At the time of writing this I could not find shortcuts for these functions.

1. Once you finished with the drawings, press F3 on your keyboard.
2. The search box will pop up and type in **Convert Grease Pencil** and click the **Gpencil: Convert Grease Pencil** option, see image below. You may see more selection in the list

[image]

3. The below menu will pop up and select the one you need.

[image]

4. The Bezier is created which you can see in the Outliner. The below image is in Edit mode showing the Bezier edit points, which I edited a bit to move it above the object and curved it to make it visible. I created an offset 3D tube extrusion here from the Bezier, that is what you see in green next to the Bezier.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in another post.
Youll find it in Object Mode, Object, Convert To

Im just find the same problem with those tutorials xD

Cheers!

Source:[grease pencil strokes to mesh is not available in 2.8 release](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147272/grease-pencil-strokes-to-mesh-is-not-available-in-2-8-release)

[image]