# grease pencil strokes to mesh is not available in 2.8 release

Tags: modeling

what just happened it was there in 2.79 beta and 2.8  alpha versions grease pencil strokes which can convert to mesh shortcut key is alt+C just disappeared in the official release or is there any way to convert grease pencil strokes to geometry in new release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it through the object menu in 3D view while in object mode (*Object > Convert to > Polygon Curve*). An option to directly convert to a regular mesh object doesn't exist, however you can convert either the polygon curve or the bezier curve to a mesh.

[image]